# Como cambiar el tamaño del footer de un modal

Tags: html5, bootstrap, asp.net-mvc

Trabajo en ASP.NET MVC 5, tengo un *modal popup* que no me muestra los botones que se le puso al `footer`. Muestro código.

HTML:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade in">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: #337ab7;border-color:#2e6da4;color:#fff;">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h5 class="modal-title">Proveedor</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="resultado"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Imagen:

[image: Footer]

Código del modal:

```
@model Demo.ServiciosDominio.Dtos.ProveedorDto

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @*<h4>Proveedor</h4>
        <hr />*@
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RazonSocial, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RazonSocial, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RazonSocial, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NumeroDocumento, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NumeroDocumento, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NumeroDocumento, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Direccion, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Direccion, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Direccion, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Telefono, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Telefono, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Telefono, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-default" />
            <input type="button" value="Cerrar" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

@*<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>*@
```

Comment: Copie y pege tu codigo y me funciono seguramente tienes algun div que no esta cerrado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debido al seguimiento que te he dado en preguntas anteriores de este proyecto, no se muestran los botones porque tienes conflicto en la clase `btn`, ya que sobrescribes la clase `btn` para los botones flotantes.

Para resolver este problema habría que cambiar el nombre de la clase `btn` de todo lo que tenga que ver con estos flotantes. Si la clase es `btn` puedes nombrarla `btnFlot`, de tal manera que te quedaría tu código como esto:

```js
$('.botonF1').hover(function(){
  $('.btnFlot').addClass('animacionVer');
})
$('.contenedor').mouseleave(function(){
  $('.btnFlot').removeClass('animacionVer');
})
```

```css
*{
  margin:0;
}
header{
  height:170px;
  color:#FFF;
  font-size:20px;
  font-family:Sans-serif;
  background:#009688;
  padding-top:30px;
  padding-left:50px;
}
.contenedor{
  width:240px;
  height:90px;
  position:absolute;
  right:0px;
  top:20px;
}
.botonF1{
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  border-radius:100%;
  background:#F44336;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  position:absolute;
  margin-right:16px;
  margin-bottom:16px;
  border:none;
  outline:none;
  color:#FFF;
  font-size:36px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
  transition:.3s;  
}
span{
  transition:.5s;  
}
span.glyphicon{
  position:relative;
  left:-3px;
  top: -6px;
  font-size:20px;
}
.botonF1:hover span{
  transform:rotate(360deg);
}
.botonF1:active{
  transform:scale(1.1);
}
.btnFlot{
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  border-radius:100%;
  border:none;
  color:#FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
  font-size:28px;
  outline:none;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  margin-right:26px;
  transform:scale(0);
}
.btn:focus{
  outline:0px;
  color:#fff;
}
.btn:hover{
  color:#fff !important;
}
.botonF2{
  background:#2196F3;
  margin-right:85px;
  transition:0.5s;
  top:0;
  margin-top:25px;
}
.botonF3{
  background:#673AB7;
  margin-right:130px;
  transition:0.7s;
  top:0;
  margin-top:25px;
}
.botonF4{
  background:#009688;
  margin-right:175px;
  transition:0.9s;
  top:0;
  margin-top:25px;
}
.botonF5{
  background:#FF5722;
  margin-right:220px;
  transition:0.99s;
  top:0;
  margin-top:25px;
}
.animacionVer{
  transform:scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header>
  <span>Pasa el mouse sobre el Boton flotante</span>
</header>
<div class="contenedor">
  <button class="botonF1">
    <span>+</span>
  </button>
  <button class="btnFlot botonF2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    <span>+</span>
  </button>
  <button class="btnFlot botonF3">
    <span>+</span>
  </button>
  <button class="btnFlot botonF4">
    <span>+</span>
  </button>
  <button class="btnFlot botonF5"> 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span> 
  </button>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade in">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content" >
      <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: #337ab7;border-color:#2e6da4;color:#fff;">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h5 class="modal-title" >Proveedor</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="resultado">12381</div>
      </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

a tu código del modal agrégale la siguiente clase.

```
    <div class="modal-footer form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-default" />
            <input type="button" value="Cerrar" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No funciona, sigue igual

Comment: hola, tienes que quitar el  <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">